# How do I calculate this probability?

Tags: probability

A student must answer $10$ questions, for each question $4$ propositions are given. If $X $is the number of correct questions, what is the probability of $5$ correct answers $\mathbb P(X=5)$?
Should we just divide $5/10$? 
if yes what about the $40$ propositions?
Should we devide $5/40$?
but we know that there is exactly $10$ correct answers.
What I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you ever heard of binomial distribution?

Comment: Nope! I'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Each question has $4$ choices so total outcomes are$4^{10}$

Now you can have five right answers in ${10}\choose 5$ ways

So probability is $\frac{{10}\choose 5}{4^{10}}$

Comment: This is not correct.  The outcomes are not equi-probable.

Comment: You have 4 choices for first answer 4 for second and so on so total cases becomes $4^{10}$ then where am I wrong

Comment: Suppose there was just one question.  then the only two outcomes are "Correct" and "Incorrect".  Your method would give $\frac 12$ as the answer which is not right, the answer is $\frac 14$.

Comment: No, i am considering 4 options and 5 right answers

Comment: Where my answer gave $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You used the binomial coefficient. Without applying the formula of binomial distribution. Can you explain what you did ?

Comment: I put all questions in a line then arranged 4options A,B,C,D then selected 5 answers and took the correct arrangement for right answer

Comment: My single question example was misleading.  Try two questions. Let's say the possible answers are $A,B,C,D$ and that $A$ is correct both times.  Say we want the probability of getting exactly one right.  How would you answer that?  Would you say $\frac {\binom 21}{4^2}=\frac 18$?  But this is clearly wrong.  The winning combinations are $AB,AC,AD,BA,CA,DA$ so the answer is $\frac 6{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

Probability questions like this one often involve the use of some combinatorics (counting techniques) to account for different outcomes. You can solve this problem using counting alone or by the Binomial Theorem.

---

**Method 1: First principles**

Setup: 10 questions each with 4 possible answers, one of which is correct.

Question: Find P(five correct answers).

Think firstly about how one might answer five of ten questions correctly. Let C be a correct and I an incorrect answer.
A person could go $CCIICCCIII$, $IIIIICCCCC$, $CIIICCIICC$ etc.

In how many ways can we arrange 5 $C$s and 5 $I$s? This is the same number of ways in which we can answer 5 questions correctly and five incorrectly i.e. this is the number of possible outcomes which are *favourable* to this experiment.

From combinatorics, $n$ objects can be arranged in $n!$ = $n(n-1)(n-2)...3*2*1$ ways in a line. Hence we can arrange our ten answers in $10! = 3 628 800$ ways IF they were all different.

But we can only have two different answer types - correct or incorrect - and we know that five of these are identical (and the other five are also identical.)

This is akin to dividing 10! by 5! (to account for arranging 5 identical correct answers) and 5! again (for the 5 incorrect answers):

i.e. number of ways to arrange 10 answers made from 5 Cs and 5 Is $ = \displaystyle \frac{10!}{5!5!}=\frac{10.9.8.7.6.5!}{5!*5.4.3.2.1} = 252$.

So there are 252 ways in which one can answer half of the paper correctly. But where does the probability fit in?

The probabilities are what we are actually arranging! Now, only one of the four answers is correct so $P(C) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{4}$ and $P(I) = \displaystyle \frac{3}{4}$.

The trials (answering questions) are successive and independent. This means that previous question attempt does not affect the next one and so

P(5 C) = $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{4} * \displaystyle \frac{1}{4} *  ... $ to 5 factors $= (\displaystyle \frac{1}{4})^5$.

P(5 I) $= (\displaystyle \frac{3}{4})^5$ in a similar way.

The above, however, only applies if there are only 5 questions in total. We are told that there are ten questions of which five are correct.

So we simply combine everything as follows:

$\Pr$(5 correct and 5 incorrect) $ = \Pr(C)^5 * \Pr(I)^5 * $ (the number of ways in which we can arrange 5 P(C)s and 5 P(I)s).

$ = \displaystyle \frac{10!}{5!5!} * (\frac{1}{4})^5 * (\frac{3}{4})^5 $

$ = \displaystyle \binom{10}{5} * (\frac{1}{4})^5 * (\frac{3}{4})^5 $

$ = \displaystyle \frac{243 * 252}{1 048 576} $

$ = 0.058 (3DP)$

---

**Method 2: Binomial expansion**

Since there are two options of answering a question in this test, we can model the probability distributions using a binomial expansion.

Let our model be given by:

$\displaystyle \sum \Pr = (\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4})^{10} = 1$

From the Binomial Theorem we can write $\displaystyle (\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4})^{10}$ as

$ \displaystyle \binom{10}{0} (\frac{1}{4})^0 (\frac{3}{4})^{10} +  \binom{10}{1} (\frac{1}{4})^1 (\frac{3}{4})^9 + \binom{10}{2} (\frac{1}{4})^2 (\frac{3}{4})^8 + ... +\binom{10}{5} (\frac{1}{4})^5 (\frac{3}{4})^5 + ... + \binom{10}{10} (\frac{1}{4})^{10} (\frac{3}{4})^0 $

where each term is of the form $ \displaystyle \binom{10}{r} (\frac{1}{4})^r (\frac{3}{4})^{10-r}$ and is the probability of answering $r$ answers correctly.

Hence we put $r = 5$ and compute

$\Pr$(5 correct and 5 incorrect) = $\displaystyle \binom{10}{5} (\frac{1}{4})^5 (\frac{3}{4})^5 = 0.058 $ as above.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We use **Binomial Distribution** here. The formula that finds the probabilities for the binomial distribution for probability of success $p$, fixed number of trials $n$, and $k$ successes is as follows: $$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ Here $p$ stands for the probability of a correct answer and obviously $(1-p)$ for that of a wrong answer. Let $X$ denote the variable to represent the number of total correct answers in the quiz. We need to calculate $P(X=5)$. Using $p=0.25$ as there is equal probability of choosing any of the five options. Using the distribution formula, we get, $$P_{req} = \binom{10}{5}(0.25)^5(0.75)^5 = 0.058$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is correct, someone pointed out binomial distribution in the comments. I applied the formula and I got the same result as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I am using bionomial distribution to solve this question.

$p( \text{correct answer}) = \frac{1}{4}$

As only 1 option correct out of 4.

Then,

$q( \text{incorrect answer}) = 1 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$

Now according to bionamial distribution

$P(X=r) = C(n,r) (q)^{n-r} (p)^r$

Here X = 5 as correct answer and n = 10 total questions.

$P(X=5) = C(10,5) * \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^5 * \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^5 $